# Postgres Text data type truncation issue

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.3. When I insert a large string into a column with a data type of "text" it keeps getting truncated to 256 characters.

I am so confused. The Postgres docs say that the "text" data type is variable and of unlimited length.

Please help!

Comment: Unlike some other DBMS, Postgres does **not** silently truncate values. If a value is too large to fit into a column you will receive an error. Your values are truncated by whatever code is running the SQL statements and sending the values to the database.

Comment: Thanks for including your version. It's also helpful if you include details like the language and client driver being used, if you're connecting with a particular application framework or program.

Answer (score 0):

Your application framework is truncating the values. PostgreSQL never truncates values for `text` or `varchar`. It *will* truncate values for the legacy `character` whitespace padded type, but only on explicit casts.

```
CREATE TABLE testtruncation(
    text_unlimited text,
    text_limit255 text check (length(text_limit255) <= 255),
    varchar_unlimited varchar,  
    varchar_255 varchar(255), 
    char_nosize character,
    char_255 character(255)
);

regress=> insert into testtruncation(text_unlimited) values ('abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789');
INSERT 0 1

regress=> insert into testtruncation(text_limit255) values ('abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789');
ERROR:  new row for relation "testtruncation" violates check constraint "testtruncation_text_limit255_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEF..., null, null, null, null).

regress=> insert into testtruncation(varchar_unlimited) values ('abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789');
INSERT 0 1

regress=> insert into testtruncation(varchar_255) values ('abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789');
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)

regress=> insert into testtruncation(char_nosize) values ('abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789');
ERROR:  value too long for type character(1)

regress=> insert into testtruncation(char_255) values ('abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789');
ERROR:  value too long for type character(255)
```

The only time values will get truncated is with an explicit cast to `character(n)`:

```
regress=> SELECT CAST('abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP0123456789' AS character(20));
        bpchar        
----------------------
 abcdefghijklmnopABCD
(1 row)
```

but it's always better to use `substring` instead of that, and in any case it's very unlikely this could be happening without your knowledge.